In Rust, which type declaration is closest to a type declaration nested in a generic class in C# or C++?
(This is the Rust version, for Scala version, please go to In Scala or other JVM language, which type declaration is closest to a type declaration nested in a generic class in C# or C++?)
When writing a library that relies heavily on generic/template in C# or C++, one trick I often use is to declare several structs that uses the same generic type arguments as nested types under a static class.
e.g. these declaration (using C# as an example):
    public struct Gen1<T1, T2, T3>
    {
    }

    public struct Gen2<T1, T2, T3>
    {
    }

is functionally equivalent to this:
    public static class Ts<T1, T2, T3>
    {
        public struct Gen1
        {
        }

        public struct Gen2
        {
        }
    }

Namely, Ts<int, int, string>.Gen1 is converted to a specialised class by the compiler, with its own static members. Ts<int, int, String> and Ts<int, int, int> becomes 2 different classes that shares nothing except names.
I have not found similar abstract in most other languages (the only exception is LEAN4, where the static generic class becomes a section: https://lean-lang.org/lean4/doc/sections.html). When converting such code to Rust, most LLMs will suggest using mod feature (which has no generic/template) and give an obviously defective answer, e.g. the following answer from Claude 3.5:
mod container<T> {
    pub struct Holder {
        value: T,
    }

    impl<T> Holder {
        pub fn new(value: T) -> Self {
            Holder { value }
        }

        pub fn get(&self) -> &T {
            &self.value
        }
    }
}

What's the easiest/shortest way to convert such declaration?

Rust does not support defining structs within structs (and yeah mod can't introduce generics). So the Rust equivalent would look like the first C# snippet.

thanks a lot @kmdreko, that sounds very repetitive

I would advice against using LLMs for learning purposes, besides asking very basic facts. From my experience, they are almost always wrong when asked more advanced questions, but often in a subtle way (ie. most of then answer is correct, but not all of it), which is IMO very harmful for the learning process.

Rust does not support defining structs within structs (and yeah mod can't introduce generics). So the Rust equivalent would look like the first C# snippet; Gen1 and Gen2 need to be defined seperately with their own generic parameters.

If you want Ts to have some strong association with Gen1 and Gen2, you can do that with an associated type declaration but it can only be through a trait implementation (until inherent associated traits are supported). Here's how that could look in Rust:
struct TsGen1<T1, T2, T3> {
    // ... fields
}

struct TsGen2<T1, T2, T3> {
    // ... fields
}

struct Ts<T1, T2, T3> {
    // ... fields
}

trait Gen {
    type Gen1;
    type Gen2;
}

impl<T1, T2, T3> Gen for Ts<T1, T2, T3> {
    type Gen1 = TsGen1<T1, T2, T3>;
    type Gen2 = TsGen2<T1, T2, T3>;
}

Then you could refer to the "nested" types as Ts<A, B, C>::Gen1. Helpful if you want that organization, but not helpful if you're just trying to simplify definitions.

looks all good, but let's wait for few days for an answer that simplifies definition (with or without macro/meta)

I could imagine a decent solution with macros but its not exactly my thing

There is no scope-based binding, as in Lean, in Rust. Besides, having a solution like the one you have described in C# would interact poorly with some more subtle aspects of Rust's type system, mainly because Rust's polymorphism is not like C++ templates where the compiler copy-pastes each type polymorphic definition properly instantiated at each use site.
However, this doesn't mean that you cannot write less verbose code. Indeed, if it makes sense to group together the type bindings, they you can group them with a trait:
// setup code
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait Bindings {
  type T1;
  type T2;
  type T3;
}

struct Argument<T1, T2, T3>(PhantomData<(T1, T2, T3)>);

impl<T1, T2, T3> Bindings for Argument<T1, T2, T3> {
  type T1 = T1;
  type T2 = T2;
  type T3 = T3;
}

// actual types
struct Gen1<B: Bindings> {
  field1: B::T1,
  field2: B::T2,
  field3: B::T3,
}

struct Gen2<B: Bindings> {
  ...
}

A disadvantage now is that instantiating such a polymorphic type becomes a little bit more verbose: Gen1<Argument<..., ..., ...>> instead of Gen1<..., ..., ...>.
Another big disadvantage is that this is a not so common idiom, so it really makes your code more complex than the equivalent, verbose version.

Finally, I have to say that, even in Lean, where you have section-scoped bindings, I personally find that they are seldom useful. The gain from the verbosity standpoint is often counterbalanced by the additional complexity to track down the exact dependencies between arguments that are declared at the section level. I only use them when the type of the arguments becomes prohibitive for the readability of the signature, which is very rare in Rust since it doesn't have dependent types.
